# IllegalStateException: database not open at the second application entering, ORMLite

Tags: android, dao, ormlite, illegalstateexception

I use my databaseHelper:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) 
{
     try
     {  

        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Category.class);
        Log.i(DatabaseHandler.class.getName(), "created new entries in onCreate: " );
     }
     catch (SQLException e){
         Log.e(TAG, "error creating DB " + DATABASE_NAME);
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
}

// Upgrading database
  @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVer, int newVer)
  {
       try
        {         

           TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Category.class, true);
           onCreate(db, connectionSource);
        }
       catch (SQLException e){
           Log.e(TAG,"error upgrading db "+DATABASE_NAME+"from ver "+oldVer);
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }

   }
 public Dao<Category, Integer> getCategoryDao() throws SQLException 
    {
        if (simpleCategoryDao == null) {
            simpleCategoryDao = getDao(Category.class);
        }
        return simpleCategoryDao;
    }

  public static synchronized DatabaseHandler getHelper(Context context) 
   {
        if (helper == null) 
        {
            helper = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        }
        usageCounter.incrementAndGet();
        return helper;
    }
```

And I get JSON data, wrap it to my model and save it in the ORMLite..My I do it in the AsyncTask inner class. My doInBackground method in it.

```
        protected Void doInBackground(String... param) {
             ContentRepository _contactRepo;
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            json = userFunction.loginUser(param[0], param[1]);
            try {
                if ((json.getString(KEY_STATUS) != null) & json.getString(KEY_MESSAGE).equals((String)"Success"))
                {

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_STATUS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1)
                    {   

                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
                        appendLog(json.toString());
                        DataParsing u = new DataParsing();
                        List<Category> catlist = u.wrapCategories(json);
                        List<ProcessStatus> status = u.wrapStatuses(json);
                        List<Level> level = u.wrapLevels(json);
                        List<Subject> subject = u.wrapSubjects(json);

                        _contactRepo=new ContentRepository(getContentResolver(),getApplicationContext());

                        OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper dbHelper=getHelper1();
                        getHelper1().open();

                        Dao<Category, Integer> daoCat=dbHelper.getDao(Category.class);
                        QueryBuilder<Category,Integer> catquery = daoCat.queryBuilder();
                        try{
                            getHelper1().open();    
                            if (catquery.query().isEmpty())
                            {
                                _contactRepo.saveCategories(catlist);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IllegalStateException e)
                        {
                            getHelper1().open();            
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                        Log.i("category",catquery.query().toString());

                    }   
                }
```

And getHelper1() method:

```
private DatabaseHandler getHelper1() {
        if (databaseHandler == null) {
            databaseHandler = DatabaseHandler.getHelper(this);
        }
        return (DatabaseHandler) databaseHandler;
    }
```

When I start the application, everything works fine. When I try to lauch it in second time I get:

```
 08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:154)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:57)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.<init>(SelectIterator.java:55)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:206)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:155)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:261)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.query(QueryBuilder.java:262)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:329)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-21 15:44:48.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1893):     ... 4 more
08-21 15:44:54.589: I/destroy(1893): destroy
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893): Activity com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40668ff0 that was originally added here
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40668ff0 that was originally added here
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:263)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity$LoginTask.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:239)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity$5.onClick(LoginActivity.java:195)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-21 15:44:54.839: E/WindowManager(1893):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But when I start application one more time - everything works fine again. On the next time - I get exceptions again.

My open() method in helper class:

```
  public void open() throws SQLException {
      helper.getReadableDatabase();
      helper.getWritableDatabase();

  }
```

Comment: Related to delete question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005564/illegalstateexception-database-not-open-at-the-second-application-entering-ever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So all of the [ORMLIte](http://ormlite.com/) Android examples have a similar pattern that I believe you may be violating.  You need to make sure that you remove any cached DAOs when the application is closed.  For example, the [HelloAndroid example](http://ormlite.com/docs/android-examples) has the following method in its `DatabaseHelper`.

```
public void close() {
    super.close();
    simpleDao = null;
    simpleRuntimeDao = null;
}
```

I also see that you are calling `getHelper1().open();` but I have no idea what that method is doing. The helper will be opened when by Android's `SQLiteOpenHelper` -- you shouldn't need to open it yourself.

I see that `getHelper()` returns a `DatabaseHandler`. I don't know that class.  Is that a typo?  Built into the `OrmLiteBaseActivity` and similar classes is a `getHelper()` method which knows when to invalidate it and create a new one.  You should make sure you are using them.

Also, I see a `getHelper()` method on the helper class itself along with a `usageCounter`.  I would go back to the pattern from the [HelloAndroid example](http://ormlite.com/docs/android-examples) and remove all of these customizations unless you have good reason to have them.  Your customizations are what is confusing things here.

Comment: I added open() method in my question. I use close() method in my DatabaseHandler class as you advise and I added Log.i("some text") to check if it can be called. I started the app. Everything works fine - database was created and data parsed and could be read successfully. In the end of all operation I canceled the app and get message "some text" in my logcat. So the method was called. Then I started the app one more time. And it caused exception that I typed in my post.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 DatabaseHelper db = getHelper1();
```

In your `getHelper1()` you return a `DatabaseHelper` class type, but you have it assigned to OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper. You also don't appear to use the `db` variable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you face this problem when you try to read or write something from database when you have already closed the ormlite database.  Even I faced this error.

Make sure when you try read or write operation you must have `dbhelper.getreadable()` or `getwritable()` for that.

Comment: But why does it appear every second time? Why not every time after the database creation?

Comment: I tried it. Interesting, that if I use Dao object of the class in another Activity, everything works fine and I can get all my objects from the database. So, I can say that problem is solved.

Comment: @user1512250 if ur problem is solved then please accept this answer